# Exclude standard libraries from arm-none-eabi

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, static-analysis

I am trying to perform WCET analysis using [OTAWA](https://www.tracesgroup.net/otawa/) on [tasking-Framework](https://github.com/DLR-SC/tasking-framework). However , the tool is unable to resolve indirect jump instructions. I investigated the source of these indirect jumps and I found that the included standrdad libraries are the reason for these indirect jumps.
Mainly  `fvrwrit.c, signal.c , wctromb.c, vfprint.c`.
These files are not included in the framework , but they are added due to the compiler flag
`specs= nonsys.specs`. and without this flag I got linker errors of undefined references.

Is there a way not to include the std-libraries and still have a valid .elf binary with correct control-flow graph ?
or How can I force the compiler not to generate indirect branches and replace it with direct ones ?

Comment: What linker errors do you get without specs= nonsys.specs? As OTAWA is peculiar with libraries, especially when they are used in the analyzed task, it may be worth trying to supply these methods yourself and get rid of all compiler-inserted library code. I am using -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib for OTAWA.

Comment: I get undefined reference to__exit , __start  and other functions in the standard libraries.

Comment: @achim I tried -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib , the linker gives more and more errors

Comment: sure, you would have to supply them. _start does initializations (stack pointer, etc.) and then calls main. You can bypass that by setting --entry main, or just create a _start function that calls main. If you still need an _exit function, just write an empty one. It all won't matter with OTAWA because that only analyzes the task itself. If you would want to execute on a real microcontroller all that startup stuff should come with the specific supplied environment. What is left now is the question how many other library functions are really used by the code that you would need to supply.

Comment: The indirect branches appear when analzying the main function

Comment: ok that means you don't have a problem with compiling but you have to supply code to OTAWA that it actually supports. Read the documentation on what limitations there are, and update the code accordingly. This will, for example, also mean that you have to take special care with loops where the bounds cannot statically be determined.